# Gem Conflict Running Tests Inside Sublime Text 2 -- RVM issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rvm, sublimetext2

Not quite sure what's changed in my setup, running tests inside Sublime Text 2 was working until recently ... Now, when I run an Rspec test from within Sublime Text 2 I get the following error.

This looks to me like an RVM issue, since I created a gemset a while ago. Any ideas?

Here's the error:

```
/Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated spork 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires spork 0.9.0. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/rails_projects/sample_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/brettsanders/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/brettsanders/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/brettsanders/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

Also, 
Here's my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',     '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.4.3.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: Just added it to question, thanks for your help

Comment: Does `bundle show spork` show the 0.9.0 version?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have 0.9.2 version installed and sublime text is trying to use that

either update the version of your spork in your GemFile to 0.9.2 or do

gem uninstall spork

You will be presented with options of which version to remove choose the one with 0.9.2